# Eine neue Sprache lernen - eine Sprache neu lernen: Bedeutungsunterschied?

Tags: meaning, adjective

Anlässlich einer Auseinandersetzung an anderer Stelle frage ich mich, inwieweit sich die 'Bedeutungen' dieser beiden Verbalphrasen sowohl semantisch als auch im praktischen Gebrauch unterscheiden - daher das Wort 'Bedeutungen' in Hochkommas. Hier ein Beispiel:

1. > Den meisten Flüchtlingen ist am Anfang nicht klar, was es bedeutet, *eine neue Sprache zu lernen*.
2. > Den meisten Flüchtlingen ist am Anfang nicht klar, was es bedeutet, *eine Sprache neu zu lernen*.

Der Fall liegt hier nicht so klar wie in

[*leider läuft die Auto-Nummerierung nicht weiter*]

3. Er hat einen neuen Rechner aufgesetzt (= *das Betriebssystem aufgespielt*).
4. Er hat einen Rechner neu aufgesetzt.

Das einzige, was ich bei 1. und 2. vorerst ahne, ist, dass in Satz 1 der Aspekt '*es kommt eine Sprache hinzu*' und in Satz 2 der Aspekt '*man fängt (wieder) ganz bei null an*' betont sein könnte, weswegen ich auch beim gegebenen Beispiel den zweiten Satz für besser passend halte. In 1 lernt man (für mich) tendenziell 'nur' eine **weitere** oder (überhaupt) **eine** Fremdsprache, in 2 (tendenziell) eine **völlig andere** Sprache und damit eine andere Art, die Dinge zu sehen und eine andere Art, zu leben, wie bei einem '*Neuanfang*', denn im Hintergrund sind Strukturen assoziiert wie '*nach einem Schlaganfall alles neu lernen müssen*'. Das ist aber recht spekulativ. Könnte man es belegen? Jedenfalls zeigt eine Trefferliste in DWDS, dass '*neu lernen*' überaus häufig mit '*müssen*' kombiniert ist: https://www.dwds.de/r?corpus=public;q=neu%20lernen .

Eine weitere Frage ist die nach dem **syntaktischen Status** von '*neu*' in beiden Beispielen. In 1 ist es vordergründig ein attributives Adjektiv (vordergründig, denn auch hier handelt es sich um die Neu**aneignung** von etwas und nicht um eine neu erfundene Sprache, semantisch wäre es demnach quasi-adverbial), aber was ist dieses '*neu*' in 2? Die einfachste Interpretation wäre *adverbial zu 'lernen'*, eigentlich gemeint ist aber, '*der Lerninhalt ist für den Lerner neu*', dann würde es sich auf das Objekt '*Sprache*' beziehen. Ein Objektprädikativ ist es dennoch nicht, vielleicht eine Art Depiktiv https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4dikativum#Freie_Pr%C3%A4dikative  wie '*schwarz*' in

5. 'Er trinkt seinen Kaffee schwarz.'?

Anmerkung: Vielen erscheint "eine Sprache neu lernen" nur im Sinne von "sie zum zweiten oder wiederholten Male lernen" gebraucht werden zu können. Dem steht entgegen, dass alle möglichen Sprachlernanbieter alternativ anbieten "eine Sprache neu zu lernen oder sie aufzufrischen" (so in etlichen Varianten beim Googeln nach "Sprache neu lernen"). Ich gehe davon aus, dass die Anbieter bei diesem Neu-Lernen und Auffrischen nicht dasselbe meinen.

[Die Antworten können gerne auch auf Englisch sein, ich verstehe Englisch recht gut, aber kann mich selbst nur sehr unbeholfen in dieser Sprache ausdrücken.]

Comment: "Eine Sprache neu lernen" wird für mich fast nur im Sinne von "eine Sprache erneut lernen" verwendet. z.b. "In der Schule hatte ich Französisch, aber über die Jahre habe ich alles vergessen. Im Sprachkurs werde ich die Sprache wieder neu lernen." Im deinem zweiten Beispiel also zumindest Kenntnisse der Sprache schon einmal gelernt worden sein mussten. Umgangsprachlich kann man sich evtl auch auf eine komplett neue beziehen, aber das kommt dann auf den Kontext an.

Comment: @mtwde: Dann wäre es allerdings schwierig zu erklären, warum alle möglichen Sprachlernanbieter kontrastiv anbieten "eine Sprache neu zu lernen oder sie aufzufrischen" - sie werden wohl kaum denselben Inhalt zweimal hinschreiben, siehe https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sprache+neu+lernen%22&oq=%22Sprache+neu+lernen%22&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l2.7670j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8.

Comment: +1 Dafür, dass du die Diskussion in eine eigene Frage ausgelagert hast. Sehr konstruktiv! Es ist auch wirklich eine spannende Frage.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn ich das recht sehe, hat *eine Sprache neu lernen* zwei Bedeutungen:

1. Eine Sprache, die man schon einmal gesprochen hat, erneut lernen. Etwa

> Nach seinem Schlaganfall musste er selbst seine Muttersprache wieder völlig neu lernen.

2. Beginnen, eine Sprache zu lernen. Diese Bedeutung scheint mir nicht präsent, wenn die Wortgruppe allein steht, sie wird aber präsent, wenn sie in einen Gegensatz zu Ausdrücken gebracht wird, die "eine Sprache auffrischen" bedeuten. Etwa:

> Wenn Sie Ihr Französisch auffrischen oder (ganz) neu lernen wollen, sind Sie hier richtig.

Da man immer, wenn man eine neue Sprache lernt, auch *beginnt* eine Sprache zu lernen, ist die Extension des Ausdrucks in dieser zweiten Bedeutung identisch mit der Extension des Ausdrucks *eine neue Sprache lernen*, die Intension [sic!] ist jedoch verschieden. Aus diesem Grund würde ich die beiden Ausdrücke nicht als synonym ansehen: *eine Sprache neu lernen* legt den Fokus eher auf das Beginnen, *eine neue Sprache lernen* legt den Fokus eher darauf, dass es sich um eine weitere Sprache handelt.

Comment: Tendenziell okay, aber so genau nimmt man's im täglichen Sprechen (und Schreiben) meiner Erfahrung nach nicht. Hier mal nicht kontrastiv: (zu 'Lernen im Alter':) _ Im Alter noch den Führerschein machen oder eine Sprache neu lernen?_ (swr); _Wer eine Sprache neu lernen möchte, ist bei Memrise gut aufgehoben._ (fernweh-fotos.de); _er musste die deutsche Sprache neu lernen, hatte er doch zu Hause immer Platt gesprochen._ (rp-online.de); - Zu der extensional/intensional-Geschichte vielleicht später mehr. Dass hier verschiedene Perspektiven angelegt werden, darin sind wir uns einig.

Comment: @RalfJoerres Die Frage wird mit jedem deiner Kommentare interessanter! Das Beispiel mit dem Platt könnte allerdings auch die 1. Bedeutung meinen - falls Platt gerade als Varietät des Deutschen angesprochen werden soll; das ist nicht ganz klar.

Comment: Platt ist eine andere Sprache und eher mit dem Niederländischen verwandt als mit dem Hochdeutschen.

Answer (score 1):

Meiner Ansicht nach impliziert die Formulierung *eine Sprache neu lernen*, dass man sie schon mal konnte, aber inzwischen durch langen Nichtgebrauch wieder verlernt hat.
Bei *eine Sprache neu lernen oder sie auffrischen* sehe ich eher den **graduellen Unterschied**, dass "Auffrischen" unterstellt, dass noch gewisse Rest-Kentnisse vorhanden sind, die im Zweifelsfall ausreichen würden, um sich halbwegs verständlich machen zu können (man würde in dem fremden Land nicht verhungern), aber nicht um Konversation zu betreiben, (und der Schüler beim Lernen diverser Grammatik-Regeln oder Vokabeln des Öfteren ein Wiedererkennen der Marke "*ach ja richtig, so war das*" erlebt), während "neu lernen" für mich eher bedeutet, dass der Schüler so gut wie alles vergessen hat, in dem fremden Land praktisch hilflos wäre und beim Lernen allenfalls die aller grundlegendsten Dinge wiedererkennt, während er andererseits bei vielen Regeln, die er eigentlich schon mal wusste, eher das "aha" des erstmaligen Kennenlernens empfindet.
Im Grunde genommen sind also *eine neue Sprache lernen*, *eine Sprache neu lernen* und *eine Sprache auffrischen* 3 verschiedene Dinge, die in den von Dir angeführten Angeboten von Sprachschulen wohl aus Platz- oder Prägnanzgründen zu zweien zusammengefasst wurden.

Comment: Ich kann die Argumentation nachvollziehen. Nur denke ich, dass dieses '_etwas neu lernen_' im Prinzip auch in Zusammenhängen vorkommt, bei denen es sich nicht um einen inzwischen vergessenen Lernstoff handelt: _Ich hatte keinen blassen Schimmer von Lagerwirtschaft, aber als mir die Stelle angeboten wurde, hab ich zugegriffen. Das war eine harte Zeit, ich musste das alles ganz neu lernen. Hat 14 Monate gedauert, bis keiner von der Spedition mir noch was vormachen  konnte._ Mein Eindruck ist, dass man _eine Sprache neu lernen_ auch in diesem Sinn verstehen kann. Ähnlich: _sich neu einarbeiten_.

Answer (score 0):

Ich denke man muss drei Fälle unterscheiden

> a) Eine Sprache lernen.
>
> b) Eine neue Sprache lernen.
>
> c) Eine Sprache neu lernen.

Wobei a) sicherlich eindeutig ist und eine einfache Aussage ist. Eine Sprache wird gelernt ohne weitere Details (allerdings wird man ohne Kontext davon ausgehen, dass diese zum ersten mal gelernt wird - wie lange der Lernprozess schon anhält ist dabei egal).

Bei b) kommt es schon auf den Kontext an. Auch hier soll ein Sprache gelernt werden. Diese kann allerdings an sich "neu" sein (man denke an eine neu erfundene Programmiersprache oder Esperanto oder Klingonisch etc) oder für die Person die sie lernt noch unbekannt sein. Im Normalfall und bei nicht eindeutigem Kontext wird man allerdings davon ausgehen, dass es der zweite Fall ist. Wobei selbst im ersten Fall der zweite mit impliziert ist, denn wer kennt schon bereits eine gerade erfundene Sprache ;) ).

c) ist hier ja eh der Gegenstand der Frage. Versteht man neu lernen im Sinne von

> etwas Vergessenes erneut lernen

oder auf

> etwas Neues dazulernen

Wie die Diskussion zeigt kann man Beispiele für beide Verwendungsarten finden.

---

Um das zu klären kann es hilfreich sein ähnliche Konstrukte zu betrachten.

z.B.

> etwas [neu machen](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22neu%20machen%22&start=10) (Das war Mist. Mach das mal neu.)
>
> etwas [neu streichen](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22neu%20streichen%22&start=10) (Wir streichen die Wand neu.)
>
> etwas [neu malen](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22neu%20malen%22&start=10) (Ich male das Bild neu.)
>
> [etwas neu](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22neu%20schreiben%22&start=10) [schreiben](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22buch%20neu%20schreiben%22&start=10) (Ich muss den Artikel von Grund auf neu schreiben.)
>
> jemanden [neu kennenlernen](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22neu%20kennenlernen%22) (Bei der letzten Feier habe ich meinen Freund ganz neu kennengelernt.)

Bei all diesen Beispielen würde man die Sätze im Sinne von "erneut" verstehen. Wobei man im Bild-Beispiel noch ein klein wenig diskutieren kann.

Ist jetzt "eine Sprache neu lernen" eine große Ausnahme? Damit zu argumentieren, dass man online viele Beispiele dafür findet ist noch kein Beweis, denn es gibt auch sehr viele Menschen, die "[größer als wie](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22gr%C3%B6%C3%9Fer%20als%20wie%22&start=10)" sagen und das macht es ja noch nicht richtig ;) . Aber es ist ein Hinweis. Genauso wie, dass es viel weniger Google-Suchergebnisse für ["sprache neu lernen"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sprache%20neu%20lernen%22), als ["neue sprache lernen"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22neue%20sprache%20lernen%22) gibt (ca. 2500 vs. 102.000). Dabei halte ich übrigens die Fundstellen in Zeitungen für "neu lernen" für wichtiger, als die bei den Sprachanbietern, da diese für ihr SEO-Ranking eh dem Volk aufs Maul schauen und antizipieren müssen nach welchen Wortkombinationen gesucht wird.

---

Ist es jetzt korrekt "eine Sprache neu lernen" im Sinne von eine Sprache erstmalig lernen. Nach all dem was ich bislang geschrieben habe würde ich erstaunlicherweise sagen, dass es unter bestimmten Voraussetzungen möglich ist und das Wort lernen hier manchmal eine Art Ausnahme bildet, da man lernen als kontinuierlichen Prozess begreifen kann, der immer und dauerhaft stattfindet. Denn man kann immer "neu lernen" und das ist dann entweder "etwas komplett Neues" oder "etwas erneut".

Man kann auch argumentieren, dass Sprache als ein Gesamtkonstrukt angesehen werden könnte (mal weit hergeholt). Man also aus diesem Wust aller Sprachen eine herauspickt und damit das Gesamte neu lernt.

Und selbst wenn nicht. Sprache ist immer in Bewegung und solange man verstanden wird .. who cares? Pas vrai mes amis? Das wäre genauso als wie so viele andere Wendungen die oftmals verwendet und vor allem verstanden werden. Es kommt halt auch immer auf den Kontext drauf an.

Persönlich würde ich allerdings eher "eine neue Sprache lernen" oder "eine Sprache lernen" statt "eine Sprache neu lernen" sagen, da "neu lernen" für mich auch weiterhin im Sinne von "erneut lernen" verwendet werden sollte. Analog zu den oben genannten Beispielen.

Comment: 'Neu' hat die Bedeutungspotenz 'noch einmal' / 'noch einmal besser', die schiebt sich bei quasi-adverbialer Verwendung stark in den Vordergrund (siehe Deine Beispiele). Es hat aber auch, u.a. in der Kombination 'ganz neu', die Potenz 'so von Grund auf neu, dass es mit den Vorgängeraktionen nichts mehr zu tun hat und praktisch eine Neuschöpfung darstellt'. 'Etwas neu übersetzen' fiele i.d.R. in diese Kategorie, 'sich neu aufstellen' (im Fußball / als Unternehmen mit einem völlig anderen Konzept antreten), 'die Mozart-Symphonien neu einspielen', 'ein unbekanntes Gebiet neu erschließen' ...

Comment: ... (Fortsetzung). 'Eine Wand neu streichen' kann etwa bedeuten, '_einen alten Anstrich zum x-ten Mal erneuern_', es kann aber auch verstanden werden als '_der Wand jetzt eine ganz andere Gestaltung, Farbgebung, Farbstruktur geben_'. 'Neu' ist weder auf den einen eine noch auf den anderen Aspekt festgelegt, sondern beides ist da verquickt. Du selbst kommst zu einem ähnlichen Schluss, und ich nehme mir die Freiheit, 'neu' auch beim Sprachen-Lernen in bestimmten Situationen so meinen zu wollen, wie es in vielen anderen Kontexten schon eingeführt ist: als etwas Umfassendes, Tiefergehendes, ...

Comment: ... (Fortsetzung) das sich nicht in Vokabellernen und Grammatik erschöpft, sondern meint: sich eine Sprache neu erschaffen. [Ich könnte mir vorstellen, Dein Zögern beim Bild-Beispiel hat auch diesen Grund.]